# Best option for file upload drag and drop in Web Part in Kentico

Tags: javascript, c#, kentico

I need a file upload, drag and drop option as a Web Part in Kentico. I need to upload file in file system like `D:\Uploadfile`

With that, I would also need options of adding multiple files, delete file, rename file etc...

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into existing drag and drop file upload systems in .net, and build a custom web part to contain and use this.

Just googling, and example may be 
http://ajaxuploader.com/drag-and-drop-files.htm
or as a more advanced (but paid), telerik offers some nice tools
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/draganddrop/defaultcs.aspx

The only part you would be involved with in Kentico is just wrapping it in a webpart, and possibly modifying the code if you want to save the files to the media library or such, but Kentico's documentation and API examples will help further!

Comment: As Trevor mentioned those tools will work the main concern is what file types will you be storing these as.  Do you want them within Kentico at all or just files in the file system with no reference?  Do you want them to be indexed?  Do you want them to have any permissions/security associated with them? Do you want any of the content to be searchable?  Choosing the tool to use is just the tip of the iceberg.